# Change Local EJB Interface in Remote EJB Interface - Result to the client application

Tags: interface, dependency-injection, ejb-3.0, local, remote-access

I have an application in Java EE/JSF using a local EJB Interface and I would like to use the business layer with another client application (in a different JVM).

So, I need to use a remote EJB Interface to use dependency injection in the new client application.

But if I change the EJB Interface, I'll also have to change all dependency injection in the managedBean of the "first" client application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Local interfaces use pass-by-reference, but remote interfaces use pass-by-deep-copy.  This means (1) all your parameter and return values must be serializable, and (2) you must depend on pass-by-reference, either for performance (very large Maps, etc.) or correctness (pass an object to a method, change the object, expect the result to be visible to the caller.

That said, when you say "local EJB interface", do you mean `@Local`, or do you mean EJBLocalHome?  If the former, then you can try changing to `@Remote`, and it might just work.  If the latter, then you'll need to update your interfaces to use `EJBHome`/`EJBObject`, which means you'll need to add RemoteException to all the methods on the interfaces, which means you'll need to at least update callers to handle the exception.

Comment: >Local interfaces use pass-by-reference - Though this is the original term the EJB spec used, there's a footnote in the spec about this now. Java does not have pass-by-reference, but instead passes a pointer (reference) by value. What remote interfaces use is something that you could describe as "pass-by-deep-copy".

Comment: Sure, made that update. I'm not sure I can retrain my brain/fingers from saying "pass-by-value" in the future, though :-).